# children div not stacking side by side inside parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason the video and sidebar div keep pushing each other outside of the wrapper div.  In addition, it seem like the main wrapper div is not being defined for some reason. I been messing around for hours now and it seem like nothing work . Can some give me some pointer.

https://jsfiddle.net/4z5wwq2j/

Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
 #wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
   } 
 #sidebar{
  height: 420px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: red;
 }
 #video{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #C5EFF7;
    border: 5px solid #19B5FE; 
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 65%;
    height: 420px;
    display: inline-block; 
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="video"></div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn some [Flexbox](http://flexboxin5.com)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `display: inline-block;` for the `#sidebar` div as well:

https://jsfiddle.net/4z5wwq2j/1/

```
#sidebar{
  height: 420px;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: red;
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

Set the vertical-align as well for both of them as you need.